# Why the webrtc Ice Candidate types are different from two peer connection

Tags: webrtc, ice

I have a peer connection between the web browser (chrome) and an android app.
When I query the stats to check the type of connections between two peers. I guessed that the information should have been the same, however, I saw that the two results are different.

Can anyone explain it to me?

**On android**

```
boolean success = peerConnection.getStats(statsReports -> {
    for (StatsReport report : statsReports) {
         Log.i(TAG, "report " + report.toString());
    }
}, null);
```

**Result on android (I manually filtered the Conn-audio filed)**

```
[googLocalAddress: 192.168.123.13:47063],
[localCandidateId: Cand-b6zAa+KI], 
[googLocalCandidateType: local], 
[googRemoteAddress: 192.168.123.49:50663], 
[remoteCandidateId: Cand-2rJUPD95],
[googRemoteCandidateType: local],
```

**In web browser (chrome)**

```
const reqFields = [
  'googLocalAddress',
  'googLocalCandidateType',
  'googRemoteAddress',
  'googRemoteCandidateType'
];
const connectionDetails = {};
peerConnection.getStats(stats => {
  // console.log("peer starts", stats.result());
  const filtered = stats.result().filter(e => {
    return e.id.indexOf('Conn-audio') === 0 && e.stat('googActiveConnection') === 'true';
  })[0];
  if (!filtered) return resolve({});

  reqFields.forEach(e => {
    connectionDetails[e.replace('goog', '')] = filtered.stat(e);
  });
  console.log('1111111', connectionDetails);
});
```

**Web browser result**

```
LocalAddress: "192.168.123.49:50663"
LocalCandidateType: "local"
RemoteAddress: ":47063"
RemoteCandidateType: "prflx"
```

Comment: Do you mean different by because one is saying "prflx" and the other "local"?

Comment: Yes. And the candidate ids are different too. I think it should be local local in both sides

Comment: Do you get this behavior when you have an android client communicating with a web browser client? Or is it when you connect to some client X but get these two different behaviors when you try on the web browser and android?

Comment: I have the connection between android and wweb client. But the info from two sides are different.

Comment: It should be the same wright?

Comment: I don't think they necessarily have to be the same, I will do some research to figure it out, and then I'll add an answer here

Comment: I have found the answer. They can be different. My problem is that the web client have not received the candidate from android client so that is why the connection is prflx.